# Having trouble understanding why selectById is not working and why task is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

I am using a local json data to test my RTK query queries, however I am having alot of trouble with selectById, and normalized data. Everything up to the selectById seems to be fine responseData includes the neccesary data, and the id matchs up, so I am really lost where the issue might be. Any help will be much appreicated, Thank you. (I will make sure to include everything I need is neccsary, if I am missing anything that wold be important please let me know).

Json data

```
{
    "tasks": [
    {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "example title 3",
        "description": "dsa adasdas dsa dsadas dasdas ",
        "assignedTo": "katie",
        "completeBy": "March 01, 2024 11:51:33 PM",
        "timeCreated": "February 29, 2024 11:51:48 PM",
        "timeUpdated": "March 01, 2024 5:04:27 PM"
    }
]
}
```

tasksSlice

```
import {createSelector, createEntityAdapter} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { apiSlice } from "../services/tasks";

const tasksAdapter = createEntityAdapter({})//get normalized state ids array and entities like a map kinda

const initialState = tasksAdapter.getInitialState()

export const tasksApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: builder => ({
        getTasks: builder.query({
            query: () => '/tasks',
            validateStatus: (response, result) => {
                return response.status === 200 && !result.isError
            },
            transformResponse: responseData => {
                console.log("responeData", responseData)
                return tasksAdapter.setAll(initialState, responseData);
            },            
            providesTags: (result, error, arg) => {
                if (result?.ids) {//a fail safe
                    return [
                        { type: 'Task', id: 'LIST' },
                        ...result.ids.map(id => ({ type: 'Task', id }))
                    ]
                } else return [{ type: 'Task', id: 'LIST' }]
            }
        }),
    })
})

export const {
    useGetTasksQuery,
} = tasksApiSlice

// returns the query result object
export const selectTaskResult = tasksApiSlice.endpoints.getTasks.select()

// creates memoized selector for optimization
export const selectTasksData = createSelector(
    selectTaskResult,
    tasksResults => tasksResults.data // normalized state object with ids & entities
)

//getSelectors creates these selectors and we rename them with aliases using destructuring
export const {
    selectAll: selectAllTasks,
    selectById: selectTaskById,
    selectIds: selectTaskIds
    // Pass in a selector that returns the users slice of state
} = tasksAdapter.getSelectors(state => selectTasksData(state) ?? initialState)
```

Home

```
import React from 'react';
import TaskContainer from './TaskContainer';
import { useGetTasksQuery } from './tasksSlice';

const Home = () => {
    const { data: tasks, isLoading, isSuccess, isError, error } = useGetTasksQuery('', {
        pollingInterval: 60000,
        refetchOnFocus: true,
        refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true
    });

    let content;

    if (isLoading) {
        content = <p>Loading...</p>;
    } else if (isError) {
        content = <p className="errmsg">{error?.data?.message}</p>;
    } else if (isSuccess) {
        const taskIds = tasks?.ids; // Get the array of task ids from the normalized data
        console.log(taskIds)
        if (taskIds && taskIds.length > 0) {
            content = (
                <div>
                    <h1>Home</h1>
                    {taskIds.map(taskId => (
                        <TaskContainer key={taskId} id={taskId} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            content = <p>No tasks found.</p>;
        }
    }
    return content;
};
export default Home;
```

taskContainer

```
import React from 'react';
import { selectTaskById } from './tasksSlice';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const TaskContainer = ({ id }) => {
    const task = useSelector(state => selectTaskById(state, id));
    console.log(task)
    return (
        <div>
            <p onClick={navTaskPage}>Title: {task ? task.title : 'Loading...'}</p>
            {/* Additional task details can be rendered similarly */}
        </div>
    );
};
export default TaskContainer;
```

responseData
[what responseData looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGlwW.png)

I tried referencing the docs to try to understand what could be causing the issue, but it didn't really clear up anything.